# Why do I get warnings when I try to assign the address of a variable to a pointer that was declared to point to a variable of a different type?

Tags: c, pointers

Take a look at the following program. What I don't understand is why do I have to cast the address of the variable `x` to `char*` when it actually would be absolutely useless if you think about it for a second. All I really need is only the address of the variable and all the necessary type information is already in place provided by the declaration statement `char* ptr`.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void) {
    int   x   = 0x01020309;
    char* ptr = &x; /* The GCC compiler is going to complain here. It will
                       say the following: "warning: initialization from
                       incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]". I
                       need to use the cast operator (char*) to make the
                       compiler happy. But why? */

    /* char* ptr = (char*) &x; */ /* this will make the compiler happy */

    printf("%d\n", *ptr); /* Will print 9 on a little-endian machine */


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where is the cast?

Comment: @t0mm13b it is not there, it is needed to suppress the warning.

Comment: Because doing pointer arithmetic behaves differently with different types, it might not be what the programmer intended

Comment: OP assumed that the assignment with differing types would work. This could induce side effects. A type `int` does not equate to `char *`. In some cases, adding a cast can hide/mask potential issues.

Comment: In what way is it going to behave differently? `char* ptr` is alway going to be able to access one byte of memory no matter what address it holds.

Comment: Type checking is "useless" in this case. It adds no information to the compiler. It "only" protects you from making a mistake.

Comment: Because you are initializing a `char *` with an expression of type `int *`, they are incompatible pointer types.

Comment: So, I guess the right thing to do would be to use `(void*)` as a cast?

Comment: *guess the right thing to do*, to be pedantic, in that case, put in a code comment explaining why. The guess bit, shows uncertainty on OP's part.

Comment: Beacuse that's the idea behind type-safety!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that it makes no practical difference. The warning is there to inform you that there *might* be something fishy with that assignment.

C has fairly strong type-checking, so most compilers will issue a warning when the types are not compatible.

You can get rid of the warning by adding an explicit cast `(char*)`, which is you saying:

> I know what I'm doing, I want to assign this value to my `char*` pointer even if the types don't match.

Answer (score 2):

The [C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), **6.2.5 Types**, paragraph 28 states:

> A pointer  to `void` shall  have  the  same  representation  and 
>   alignment  requirements  as  a pointer  to  a  character  type.
>   Similarly, pointers  to  qualified  or  unqualified  versions  of
>   compatible  types  shall  have  the  same  representation  and 
>   alignment  requirements.   All pointers to structure types shall have
>   the same representation and alignment requirements as  each  other. 
>   All  pointers  to  union  types  shall  have  the  same 
>   representation  and alignment  requirements  as  each  other.
>   **Pointers  to  other  types  need  not  have  the  same representation or alignment requirements.**

Since different types of pointers can have differing implementations or constraints, you can't assume it's safe to convert from one type to another.

For example:

```
char a;
int *p = &a
```

If the implementation has an alignment restriction on `int`, but not on `char`, that would result in a program that could fail to run.

Answer (score 1):

This is because pointers of different types point to blocks of memory of different sizes even if they point to the same location.

`&x` is of type `int*` which tells the compiler the number of bytes (depending on `sizeof(int)`) to read when getting data. 
Printing `*(&x)` will return the original value you entered for `x`

Now if you just do `char* ptr = &x;` the compiler assigns the address in `&x` to your new pointer (it can as they are both pointers) but it warns you that you are changing the size of the block of memory being addressed as a char is only 1 byte. If you cast it you are telling the compiler that this is what you intend. 
Printing `*(ptr)` will return only the first byte of the value of `x`.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, `x` is of type `int`. So the pointer that points to `x` should be of type `int *`. Compiler gives such error because you use a pointer which is not `int *`.

So make your pointer either `int *`, or `void *` then you don't need cast.

Answer (score 0):

Its just simple as you assign integer type to character. similarly you are trying to assign integer type pointer to character type pointer.

Now why is so because this is how c works, if you increment a character pointer it will give you one byte next address and incrementing integer pointer will give you 2 byte next address.

Comment: What about on 32bit or 64bit platform, how many bytes would an integer pointer be?

Comment: the compiler automatically determine what would be size of integer or character i guess

Comment: @t0mm13b Actually, there are a few platforms left still today, currently working with a signal processor with sizeof(int) == sizeof(char) and CHAR_BIT == 16...

Comment: @Aconcagua cool! must make things easier for you, so not surprised at all :)

Comment: @t0mm13b Actually, with common code for the DSP and classical 8-bit-byte, 32-bit-register MC and both communicating via CAN this actually rather imposed more trouble than benefit...